# msal.js: different AuthenticationResults for different environments

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

Using a basic sign in user flow policy.  The response from `acquireTokenSilent` is different in my development environment than my QA environment, even though the code is the same (promoted) and configuration in ADB2C is the same.  The main difference I am noticing is that I am not receiving the `expiresOn` property from the `AuthenticationResult` response object.

I can see that the `idTokenClaims` in `SessionStorage` are also slightly different.  The dev environment has an `at_hash` property, where the `QA` doesn't have that.

Is there any reason the response objects would be different?

I've checked all settings, but the "token lifetime settings" on both environments are the same:

```
Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes):  60
Refresh token lifetime (days):  14
Refresh token sliding window lifetime: Bounded
Lifetime length (days): 90
```

Checking the network response to the `/token` endpoint on `QA` I receive this:

```
client_info: "ey..."
id_token: "ey..."
not_before: 1638467851
refresh_token: "ey..."
refresh_token_expires_in: 86398
scope: ""
token_type: "Bearer"
```

Checking the network response to the `/token` endpoint on `DEV` I receive this:

```
access_token: "ey.."
client_info: "ey.."
expires_in: 3600
expires_on: 1638485366
id_token: "ey.."
not_before: 1638481766
refresh_token: "ey.."
refresh_token_expires_in: 86400
resource: "xxxxxx"
scope: "https://xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/demo-api/demo.all.all"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

Some relevant code:

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser'
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react'
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)
...
const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal()
useEffect(() => {
    if (account) {
      instance
        .acquireTokenSilent({
          scopes: myloginScopes,
          account
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res) {
            console.log(res.expiresOn) // <-- exists on one environment and not the other
          }
        })
    }
  }, [account, instance, inProgress])
```

Development environment info:

```
Azure ADB2C
@azure/msal-browser 2.17.0
@azure/msal-react: 1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

In QA, `myloginScopes` is null. Set it to https://xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/demo-api/demo.all.all.

Comment: Thank you!  I was hard coding a string in config to be `https://mydev.onmicrosoft.com/demo-api/demo.all.all` instead of `https://${MY_TENANT}.onmicrosoft.com/demo-api/demo.all.all`

Comment: Jas Suri - MSFT.  Thank you for the comment, but I realised later after further testing that this has not solved the issue.

Comment: Only other reason is you havent setup permissions correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#step-2-register-your-spa-and-api